# Convergence of an integral around the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a positive, continuous function around the origin. Is $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ a sufficient condition for $\int_0^1f(x)x^{-1}dx$ to be finite? If not, what is the minimal condition?

Comment: @Rebecca $f\to 0$! =)

Answer (score 1):

The condition is not sufficient. Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{|\ln( |x|)|}$ when $-1/2\lt x\lt 1/2$ and $x\ne 0$, and let $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. Between $1/2$ and $1$, let $f(x)=\frac{1}{|\ln(1/2)|}$.

I do not know of any nice sufficient condition.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.  Consider e.g. $f(x) = 1/|\ln(|x|)|$.

There is no "minimal" condition other than those that essentially restate the convergence.  Thus, for any $f$ for which the integral converges, there is
$g$ with $g/f \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$ for which the integral still converges;
for any $g$ for which the integral diverges, there is $f$ with $f/g \to 0$
for which the integral still diverges.